# How to use GNU sort with numeric data in binary format?

Tags: linux, sorting, binary-data, gnu-sort

Is there any way to use GNU Coreutils sort with 64bit numbers stored in binary file?
If file wasn't binary then `sort -n` is the solution, but I didn't find any options to use it with binary data.

File is quite large (~100GB) and if it is possible I don't want to make its' text (non-binary) copy.

Sample of data:

`$ xxd file
00292e0: 4036 1eb7 6888 d319 de6b 7402 9ca9 f116  @6..h....kt.....
00292f0: db68 7f05 199f 9d36 cf01 cb28 e49f 1116  .h.....6...(....
0029300: 0c7c 8b55 2963 ef0c 277a f2b0 38d7 2b19  .|.U)c..'z..8.+.
0029310: c83b 2614 4327 d838 820c 1bb8 444f 1731  .;&.C'.8....DO.1
0029320: 1695 cab3 cd12 092a 0691 d7e4 5fcc b01d  .......*...._...
0029330: b12b 7c1b a209 7c1c 568a 125c 541c d334  .+|...|.V..\T..4
0029340: 09a3 ecbc 8370 e205 9265 7759 a378 4e2f  .....p...ewY.xN/`

Comment: Can you paste a sample of `xxd file`?

Comment: I don't think `sort(1)` can help you. Moreover, `sort(1)` stores all the data in memory until it finishes sorting, so you will suffer badly from slashing with such a huge input. Btw, does your file purely consist of 64bit numbers?  In other words, is your file just a huge array of 64bit numbers?  Please provide us more information for suggesting better alternative ways.

Comment: Yes, it consists only of 64bit numbers from C++ ofstream::write.
But they say that "GNU sort (as specified for all GNU utilities) has no limit on input line length or restrictions on bytes allowed within lines."

Comment: Sorting such a large file is an interesting problem in its own right, and it's completely unreasonable to expect a general purpose utility (coreutils) to do it well.  n log n runtime for such a large dataset is going to be pretty bad already.  On the other hand, this task parallelizes really well.

Comment: As I thought, `sort` do sorting in external memory if needed, and actually it supports paralleling. Am I wrong?

Comment: The very first line of `man sort` says "sort - sort *lines* of *text* files". Your file has no lines, and is not text.

Answer (score 4):

The [bsort utility](https://github.com/pelotoncycle/bsort) does this.

It is a lightning fast inplace radix sort written in C.  One of the test cases for its development was a 100Gb file on a machine with 16Gb ram - took about 22 seconds or so to sort.

Comment: Please provide some example code as well. It is not recommended to only provide a link to a tool in an answer.

Comment: This was very helpful. Without your comment I would never have found bsort, and it does exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`sort(1)` will not help you here. For a small file it could be possible to split your file into lines and feed it to `sort(1)`, but not for 100G file of course.

The answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/402920/sorting-large-binary-files) on Serverfault has a link of the tool written for solving exactly your task. You can check the github project there (it seems to be written in Go so you will need to install a compiler if you decide to use it).

Quick googling does not find any other popular tool for this task written on some more popular language (and it surprises me a bit as the task itself is just a merge sort that thousands of students implement each year on their CS courses, but that's an off-topic).